# Add card to apple wallet in ios app shows error

Tags: applepay, wallet

I'm implementing Add card to Wallet functionality in my iOS app.
I already received com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning entitlement from Apple, but I'm receiving error while presenting PKAddPaymentPassViewController.[image]

Errors occurs when I'm pressing Next button. Can you help me understand, where is problem? Is it our bank issuer problem or is it development problem? I tried testing when I'm logged in with sandbox user in my device and testing threw Testflight but nothing helps.

I'm initiating PKAddPaymentPassViewController with PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration like this:

```
configuration.cardholderName = "AAA"
configuration.primaryAccountSuffix = "2658" // card last numbers
configuration.primaryAccountIdentifier = "XXX" // our card unique identifier
configuration.paymentNetwork = PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard // or whatever you add
PKEncryptionScheme is ECC_V2
```

Comment: I am new to this topic and getting exactly what you mentioned here, did you get the solution? and what will be the resolution for the same?

Comment: @user9417995 I am facing the same. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I had written an article on medium. Check if this help you https://medium.com/@kunalgupta1508/add-card-to-apple-wallet-in-app-provisioning-eae2458617bc